# GameObject not showing in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

The public game object is missing in unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Interaction_info_UI;
    Text interaction_text;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        interaction_text = Interaction_info_UI.GetComponent<Text>();
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            var selectionTransform = hit.transform;
 
            if (selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>())
            {
                interaction_text.text = selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>().GetItemName();
                Interaction_info_UI.SetActive(true);
            }
            else 
            { 
                Interaction_info_UI.SetActive(false);
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

[The script in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPHdS.png)

I've tried to download some extension to visual studio but hasn't done anything yet. The InteractableObject is a part if a different code that is working

Comment: that would suggest it hasnt compiled it so either there is something wrong, or, in another script edited or you have 2 of the same name

Answer (score -1):

I guess your script didn't compile correctly, and there are errors in the console. This is why you're not seeing changes in the editor, such as your public value. From a glance, the error is your use of `.GetComponent<>` as a conditional `bool` type:

`if (selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>())`

[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) will return `null` if it fails to get the component, so if you're looking to check if it exists on the transform, do a check for `!= null` as such: `if (selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>() != null)`

Better yet, look into [TryGetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html), which will simplify your conditional logic.

Comment: The "error" is a compile issue probably unrelated to this specific code itself .. there is no obvious error in the code itself (except maybe `InteractableObject` is missing) ;) `GetComponent` does **not** return `null` but an `InteractableObject` ... this one might return `true` for the operator `== null` yes. As mentioned here `TryGetComponent` is indeed better then calling `GetComponent` repeatedly though!

Comment: In case GetComponent fails to obtain the component, it will return null. However, the above code does not handle this scenario, leading to incorrect compilation. Although it's challenging to determine the root cause of the compilation problem without knowing the specific errors, it's worth trying this suggestion based on the limited information available.

Comment: The suggestion doesn't change the code to compile correctly .. it is a change of the runtime behavior .. the above code compiles correctly assuming the `InteractableObject` type itself exists